# How can I find dynamic elements in Gerrit's changeset page

Tags: javascript, xpath, greasemonkey, gerrit, dhtml

I want to write a Greasemonkey script to adapt some small detail of Gerrit to our team's workflow.

The problem is I cannot get the elements I'm after even in the Javascript console. I guess that's because most of it is built dynamically. If you do “View Page Source” there's almost nothing in there except loading of Javascript.

In the rendered page I cannot even find any interesting element with an id like e.g. the reply button:

```
document.getElementById("replyBtn")
```

What I'm really after is the “Resolved” checkboxes which are always on by default. I also tried XPath like

```
document.evaluate("//input", document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE)
XPathResult { resultType: 6, invalidIteratorState: false, snapshotLength: 0 }
```

It says length 0 although I see one directly above the console!

How can I get to these elements that were not in the HTML file on disk but added later? Preferrably without adding a dependency on jQuery or similar.

[image: screenshot of the page with my tries in the javascript console]

Comment: Script needs to run after page has fully loaded. Try setting the 'run-at' to `document-idle` and see if it helps.

Comment: It doesn’t even work manually in the JavaScript console after the page is completed for sure.

Comment: It is difficult to answer without knowing the exact circumstances and seeing a sample page and the code you are trying.